# Make two images appear side by side (CSS)

Tags: css, image

I'd like to do an image slider, using jQuery, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, but I have a problem: my images are not appearing side by side, but beneath each other, which is a problem because my slider is horizontal, not vertical.

Thanks

Comment: We'd like to see some code. :)

Comment: Your images are block elements, change styles to display:inline-block;

Comment: This could be helpful, sounds similar tho http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819417/css-center-two-images-in-css-side-by-side/11819439#11819439.

Comment: Well, that's what I thought, but it doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **owl carousel** for slider purposes. While to create an image slider, you need to create a container for the slider, then apply `display:inline-block` and use jquery to time the images to change or a click function to change the images. While you haven't supplied the code, we assume you haven't digged into proper ideology of slider, so recommend to study one already available in plugin market or have tutorials.