# Align Images Vertically over Horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am trying to realign my images side by side, rather than vertically. I have looked at [CSS - center two images in css side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819417/css-center-two-images-in-css-side-by-side), to no avail. My code from that link is as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Naviational Bar -->
<div width="100%" height="25%">
<div class="btn"><img class="navigational-item nav" alt="Home" src="images/buttons/home.jpg"></div>
<div class="btn"><img class="navigational-item nav" alt="Home" src="images/buttons/home.jpg"></div>
<div class="btn"><img class="navigational-item nav" alt="Home" src="images/buttons/home.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*Header and Navigational Bar*/
h1.heading {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
}

.btn {
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

/*Define Button Attributes*/
.navigational-item {
    width: 7%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-filter: contrast(50%);
    z-index: 100;
}
span.navigational-item {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: red;
}

.nav {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Is there any way I can lay the image out side by side with a 10px margin between them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to place them inline-block. most likely the image as well `.btn img{ display:inline-block }`

Comment: @EasyBB That just moves them to the left, sadly.

Comment: well you'll have to make a container for them silly.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for "btn" class:

```
.btn {      
    margin-left: 10px;            
    margin-right: 10px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: I want them centered though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your buttons into a container div like this:  (arbitrarily set here for a width of 30% -- edit accordingly)

```
<div width="100%" height="25%">
  <div id="container" style="width:30%;margin:auto">
    <div class="btn"><img class="navigational-item nav" alt="Home"  src="images/buttons/home.jpg"></div>
    <div class="btn"><img class="navigational-item nav" alt="Home"  src="images/buttons/home.jpg"></div>
    <div class="btn"><img class="navigational-item nav" alt="Home"  src="images/buttons/home.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then set the display property of your buttons to inline-block:

```
.btn {
 /*display: inline-block;*/
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-right: 10%;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

See pen here: http://codepen.io/Bangkokian/pen/eppbYL

Comment: Because you have no image src.

Comment: I noticed that, however the images were defined in CSS with background-image.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this basic idea :

```
#container {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {  
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

/* Below is trivial for reszing */

.navigational-item {
  width: 50px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKKRMe?editors=110

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the parameters of the images? If so we'll do this

```
<div class="image_container">
    <div class="center">
        <div class="btn">
            <img src="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image_container { position: relative }
.center {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    width: 970px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -485px;
    /*margin left is width / 2*/
} 
.btn {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

**DEMO HERE**

http://jsbin.com/fexasivori/1

**EDITED** 
updated the link and the CSS I mistakenly wrote the wrong math for the margin-left parameter. `970` divided by 2 is not `435` it is `485`

Comment: That works fine for that image (xD), however mine which has a much higher resolution even though it is scaled in CSS down to 7%, doesn't want to show horizontally.

Comment: what do you mean horizontally? Fix the rest with your own knowledge. Like I said change the width of `center` then the `margin` which will be `0 0 0` plus width divided by two. I **WOULD NEVER** use a hi-res image scaled to 7% that is just horrible designing