# How do I get pictures side by side (responsive)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How do I get these pictures side by side with css I cant get it to work.
I tried everything but nothing is working for me and I cant find a tutorial for what I need on the web pls help me. and it has to be responsive.

### HTML:

```
<div class="seizoenen">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="image/zomer.jpg" height="100%" width="25%" />
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="image/herfst.jpg" height="100%" width="25%" />
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="image/winter.jpg" height="100%" width="25%" />
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="image/lente.jpg" height="100%" width="25%" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bs3fz70v/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - center two images in css side by side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819417/css-center-two-images-in-css-side-by-side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/bs3fz70v/2/

if you want it to be responsive...

- Change `img` tags to `max-width` and set this in CSS. This will scale image down once it hits smaller screens.
- Focus on your parent and child element structure. Your `.container` `width` should be set to `25%`, not your `img` tag.
- You mentioned text overlay in your comment. Set `.container` (parent element) to `position: relative;` Set any tag (child element) within that `.container` to `position: absolute;`. Now you can set `top` or `left` any value within 100% and contain it within that `.container`. And since the `img` tag is `max-width:100%;`, it will take on full width of that container, which is 25%.
- Also set `height` to `auto` so images aren't stretched.

**CSS**

```
.seizoenen{
    width:100%;
}
p { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
.container{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24%;
    position: relative;
}
img{
   max-width: 100%; 
}
```

Hope this gets you started experimenting with more positioning

Answer (score 0):

Hoi bart, its quite easy to do. Your container needs to be `display: inline-block;` this will place the images next to eachother. And to fill the space of the images make them width: 100%;

Right [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bs3fz70v/1/) now

One thing wasn't really clear to me you want the images to scale to a smaller size aswell?

Comment: It doesnt work for me I just cant get it to work :( there also has to be text over the images I just cant get it working