# align images side by side in html

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want 3 images side by side with caption, at the moment I have 3 images going from top to bottom, with the caption on the left, not on the centre. How do I make the images appear side by side with caption in the middle? Thanks.

```
<div class="image123">
    <img src="/images/tv.gif" height="200" width="200" style="float:left">
    <p>This is image 1</p>
    <img class="middle-img" src="/images/tv.gif"/ height="200" width="200">
    <p>This is image 2</p>
    <img src="/images/tv.gif"/ height="200" width="200">
    <p>This is image 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - center two images in css side by side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819417/css-center-two-images-in-css-side-by-side)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display two images side by side on an HTML Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839318/display-two-images-side-by-side-on-an-html-page)

Answer (score 24):

You mean something like this?

```
<div class="image123">
    <div class="imgContainer">
        <img src="/images/tv.gif" height="200" width="200"/>
        <p>This is image 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">
        <img class="middle-img" src="/images/tv.gif"/ height="200" width="200"/>
        <p>This is image 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer">
         <img src="/images/tv.gif"/ height="200" width="200"/>
        <p>This is image 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the imgContainer style as

```
.imgContainer{
    float:left;
}
```

Also see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hYE2d/1/).

Comment: thank you, but how come you dont mention the class in the CSS page, how does the div in the CSS page know you are referring to image class="image123". Also do you know how to put text in centre of image?

Comment: If your going to use float to do this you should clear it too, save yourself a whole world of pain further down the line. Personally I think display:block is a better solution to this problem. floats should be used sparingly and where there is an alternative, not at all.

Comment: I didn't use the image123 or middle-img classes. I should have taken them out. I'm not sure what you mean by text in the centre of the image, do you mean so that it is on top of the image? @Liam Thanks for your tips, I never knew about floated items not adding to their parents height, that explains why I've seen that from time to time! What's the advantage of clearing over giving the parent auto overflow? It seems messy to be adding an extra div?

Comment: Overflow:auto is a method of clearing floats. [There are a couple.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Comment: Also my comment above should read `display:inline-block`...?!

Comment: 8 years further on and someone upvoted this bringing me back here. I would certainly recommend using `inline-block` as @Liam suggested rather than `float: left` everywhere here (horrible).

Comment: or better yet, in 2022, use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) @James

Comment: @Liam gimme 8 years and I'll get there.

Comment: How do you make content **after** images be displayed in the usual vertical way?

Answer (score 8):

Not really sure what you meant by "the caption in the middle", but here's one solution to get your images appear side by side, using the excellent `display:inline-block` :

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset=utf-8 />
      <title></title>
      <style>
        div.container {
          display:inline-block;
        }
    
        p {
          text-align:center;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" height="200" width="200" />
        <p>This is image 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <img class="middle-img" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/ height="200" width="200" />
        <p>This is image 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" height="200" width="200" />
        <p>This is image 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yes, I would recommend this over floats.

Comment: hello, do you know if it is possible to change the font of the text under the image? Would I have to use CSS.

Comment: @user3809938 : hi, maybe you should have a look at CSS basics, don't you think ? And more specifically to [font-family](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-family). Guess that wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 4):

Try using this format

```
<figure>
   <img src="img" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
   <figcaption>Fig1. - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

This will give you a real caption (just add the 2nd and 3rd imgs using `Float:left` like others suggested)

Comment: Bear in mind this is [very badly supported in IE browsers](http://caniuse.com/html5semantic)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use a container for each `img` `p` like this:

```
<div class="image123">
    <div style="float:left;margin-right:5px;">
        <img src="/images/tv.gif" height="200" width="200"  />
        <p style="text-align:center;">This is image 1</p>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-right:5px;">
        <img class="middle-img" src="/images/tv.gif/" height="200" width="200" />
        <p style="text-align:center;">This is image 2</p>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-right:5px;">
        <img src="/images/tv.gif/" height="200" width="200" />
        <p style="text-align:center;">This is image 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then apply `float:left` to each container. I add and `5px` `margin right` so there is a space between each image. Also alway close your elements. Maybe in html `img` tag is not important to close but in XHTML is.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J9EwM/4/)

Also a friendly advice. Try to avoid inline styles as much as possible. Take a look here:

**html**

```
<div class="image123">
    <div>
        <img src="/images/tv.gif" />
        <p>This is image 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class="middle-img" src="/images/tv.gif/" />
        <p>This is image 2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="/images/tv.gif/" />
        <p>This is image 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
div{
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}

div > img{
   height:200px;
    width:200px;
}

p{
    text-align:center;
}
```

It's generally recommended that you use linked style sheets because:

- They can be cached by browsers for performance
- Generally a lot easier to maintain for a development perspective

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013532/inline-style-tags-vs-inline-css-properties)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J9EwM/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/T5Hfq/).

**CSS**

```
.imageContainer {
    float: left;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="image123">
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <img src="/images/tv.gif" height="200" width="200" />
        <p>This is image 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <img class="middle-img" src="/images/tv.gif"/ height="200" width="200" />
        <p>This is image 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageContainer">    
        <img src="/images/tv.gif"/ height="200" width="200"/>
        <p>This is image 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, (however I would use an external style sheet for this project and all others.  just makes things easier to work with. Also this example is with html5.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
  .container {
      display:inline-block;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <figure>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" height="200" width="200">
    <figcaption>This is image 1</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
    <img class="middle-img" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/ height="200" width="200">
    <figcaption>This is image 2</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" height="200" width="200">
    <figcaption>This is image 3</figcaption>
    </figure>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```