# How to get 2 pictures to appear side by side is this html example?

Tags: html, css

How do I get 2 pictures to appear side by side in this particular html example?

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/ko1qsbom/)

What I want is to align pictures side by side in html, and similarly for the `h1` tag above and the `p` tag below the pic.

illustration of what I want:

```
title0------------title1
pic0--------------pic1
word0-------------word1
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is an example of what I want [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/4k2zfc0f/), but here it doesn't work when I want add the `h1` tag above and the `p` tag below the picture. I do, however like the way `margin-right` can control the lateral distance between the pics.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680030/align-images-side-by-side-in-html) is a similar question but this is slightly different.

**EDIT1** here is the [bootstrap](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/ko1qsbom/3/) version mentioned below

**EDIT2** here are other solutions from below

Amitesh Kumar - https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/ko1qsbom/9/
YoYo - https://jsfiddle.net/ThetHlaing10/ko1qsbom/2/
Michael_B - https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/ko1qsbom/8/
BTruong - https://jsfiddle.net/ko1qsbom/6/

they all offer a solution but I think the bootstrap version is the best as it handles when the screen width is resized the best.tks

Comment: Are you opposed to using something like Bootstrap? If not, you could just use the grid system. See here: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: familiar with bs but sould like to go back to basics here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display:inline-block;` to set the element to just use the width they have. Normally, h1 or div are the `display:block;` elements.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ThetHlaing10/ko1qsbom/2/) for you.

Answer (score 1):

Side-by-side positioning is simple and easy with flexbox.

Here's all you need:

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;  /* optional */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <section>
        <h1 class="left">title0 </h1>
        <img class="left" src="img_tree.png" alt="pic0" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
        <p class="left"><a>word0</a></p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h1 class="right">title1 </h1>
        <img class="right" src="img_tree.png" alt="pic1" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
        <p class="right"><a>word0</a></p>
    </section>

</div>
```

There are various options for aligning the two sections in the row (center, space-between, flex-start, etc.). See here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

---

Learn more about flexbox here: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*

Comment: And is that what you want? Or do you need adjustments?

Comment: pretty much what I wanted initially, but then when you change the screen size, bootstrap seem to handle this  scenario best.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is put title0, pic0, and word0 in a div and add a class to the div so you can float it to the left using css.  On the other side you have title1, pic1, and word1 in a div that has a class that would float it to the right.

Here's the float in work:

```
.leftBlock {
     float: left;
}

.rightBlock {
     float: right;
}
```

Check out this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ko1qsbom/6/

Also more information on floats: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing. The reason why I think this is preferable is because it makes sense to group each data set together. Also, you can append more image sets and the styles would apply to all of them, depending on how you assign class names and write the css.

Comment: but what if width increases

Comment: Increasing the width with my code would pull the divs further and further away from each other.  If you wanted them to stay next to each other, you could put the leftBlock and rightBlock divs in another div and have that div set at a specific width.

Answer (score 0):

Try This give them witdth total width should be less then 100% and `float:left`

**HTML**

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<p>W3Schools background image example.</p>
<p>The background image is only showing once, but it is disturbing the reader!</p>

<!--<h1 class="left">title0 </h1> --> 
<img class = "left" src="img_tree.png" alt="pic0" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
<!-- <p class="left"><a>word0</a></p> -->


<!-- <h1 class="right">title1 </h1> --> 
<img class = "right" src="img_tree.png"  alt="pic1" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
<!-- <p class="right"><a>word0</a></p> -->
```

**CSS**

```
/*
img.right{
float: left;
margin-right: 300px;
}
*/
h1.left p1.left {
text-align: left;
float:left
}

h1.right p1.right{
text-align: right;
}
.div1 {
  width:40%;
   float: left;
}
.div2 {
  width:40%;
  float: left;
}
```

you can use `display:inline-block;` also