# How do you put two images side by side with captions

Tags: html, css, markdown

I am trying to put two images side by side in Jupyter's markdown. We can use `html` but I am unable to put two images side by side with **caption**. I tried every option in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680030/align-images-side-by-side-in-html/24680211) but did not work.

```markdown
<figure>
<img src='aaa.png' width="350" height="350" align="center"/>
    <figcaption align = "center"><b>Fig 2.5; Courtesy of Linear Algebra: Theory, Intuition, Code by Mike X Cohen</b></figcaption>
<img src='bbb.png' width="350" height="350" align="center"/>
    <figcaption align = "center"><b>Fig 2.3; Courtesy of Linear Algebra: Theory, Intuition, Code by Mike X Cohen</b></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check this out**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
    <figcaption>Fig.1 - Trulli</figcaption>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
    <figcaption>Fig.2 - Puglia</figcaption>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <figcaption>Fig.3 - Italy</figcaption>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, how I type the figure styling in markdown? I am using jupyter notebook.

Comment: you should include a custom.css file with these styling code and link it your project..**To customize it using CSS, you need to check a file named custom. css in the directory ~/. jupyter/custom. If you have it, you can add some CSS code to it**

Comment: if this Answers helped you ,so dont forget to upvote it..thanks

Answer (score 0):

```css
figure{text-align: center; max-width: 40%; float:left; margin:0;padding: 10px;}
figure img{width: 100%;}
```

```html
<figure>
<img src='aaa.png'/>
    <figcaption align = "center"><b>Fig 2.5; Courtesy of Linear Algebra: Theory, Intuition, Code by Mike X Cohen</b></figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
<img src='bbb.png'/>
    <figcaption align = "center"><b>Fig 2.3; Courtesy of Linear Algebra: Theory, Intuition, Code by Mike X Cohen</b></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thanks, how I type the figure styling in markdown? I am using jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

if yes use `Flex` property

```
<div class="outerlayer">
<figure>
  <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Trulli" style="width:100%">
  <figcaption>Fig.1 - Trulli, Puglia, Italy.</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Trulli" style="width:100%">
  <figcaption>Fig.1 - Trulli, Puglia, Italy.</figcaption>
</figure>
</div
```

Styling

```css
.outerlayer{
display: flex;/* arranges both images side by side*/
column-gap: 10px; /* To give a gap between both*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope, you want something like this!

```css
figure {display: flex;}
div {border:2px solid black; width:200px; padding:5px; margin:0 10px; text-align:center;}
```

```html
<figure>
  <div>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/200'/>
    <figcaption>Fig 2.5; Courtesy of Linear Algebra: Theory, Intuition, Code by       Mike X Cohen</figcaption>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/200'/>
    <figcaption> Fig 2.3; Courtesy of Linear Algebra: Theory, Intuition, Code by      Mike X Cohen </figcaption>
  </div>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the figure styling `figure {display: flex;}
div {border:2px solid black; width:200px; padding:5px; margin:0 10px; text-align:center;}` does not work in jupyter's markdown. The below code works but without which still won't show side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to put image side by side with caption

```html
<style>
figure{
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<figure>
    <img src='image.jpg' alt='image 1' />
    <figcaption>Caption goes here</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
    <img src='image.jpg' alt='image 1' />
    <figcaption>Caption goes here</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are all basic inline styles to align your images side by side with captions. Hope this works in Jupyter Notebook.

```html
<div class="container" style="display: inline-block;">  
  <figure>
  <div style="float: left; padding: 10px;">
    <img src='aaa.png' width="350" height="350" align="center"/>
    <figcaption align="center"><b>Fig 2.5; Courtesy of Linear Algebra: Theory,<br> Intuition, Code by Mike X Cohen</b></figcaption>
  </div>

  <div style="float: right; padding: 10px;">
    <img src='bbb.png' width="350" height="350" align="center"/>
    <figcaption align="center"><b>Fig 2.3; Courtesy of Linear Algebra: Theory,<br> Intuition, Code by Mike X Cohen</b></figcaption>
  </div>
  </figure>
</div>
```